# Getting text without HTML tags from JTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I have created a text editor using a JTextPane that allows the user to make style changes to the text (bold, color. underline, etc.) The text and applied style settings are stored in HTML. So the text pane is set up to format the text on the back end into html. Here's some of the basic set up for the text pane:

```
HTMLEditorKit editorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
this.setEditorKit(editorKit);
this.setDocument(editorKit.createDefaultDocument());
this.setContentType("text/html");
```

My question is how can I get the text from the text pane without the html attached to it. Basically I want to be able to just get the text that the user sees. I need to be able to determine the character length of the text inside the pane. But when I call getText on the pane, it will give me all the text including the html. Is there a way to retrieve just the text that the user sees without the HTML? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
this.getDocument().getText(0,this.getDocument().getLength())
```

Document has plain text and all the HTML formatting is the document's structure and attributes applied to the same text.

Comment: I had seen this done before and it seems like the simplest solution. Although, does it retain line breaks? And to add to this, what would be a good way to determine how many rows (lines of text) are in the raw text?

Comment: Line breaks? You mean \n chars? or visible line breaks? The visibe ones depend on width and can be calculated with javax.swing.text.Utilities.getRowsStart/End. The \n chars has no sense in html text. All the formatting are achieved by tags